# How can I determine the sequence generated by this generating function: $B(x)=(x+3)^2 + \frac{x}{(1-3x)^6}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

How to find the sequence that is generated by this GF?

$B(x)=(x+3)^2 + \frac{x}{(1-3x)^6}$

*We know that $\frac{1}{(1-ax)}$ is generated by $\sum_{i=0}^n a^n x^n$*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remember that
$$
\frac{1}{(1-z)^m} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( m+n-1\atop n\right) z^n
$$
This can be proven by using induction and the fact that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \left( m+k\atop k \right) = \left( m+n+1 \atop n\right)
$$

Comment: that's $1/(1+z)^m$ !

Comment: This is what I was missing. Thank you so much!